# How does --data option work in curl

Tags: linux, curl

```
curl --data "<xml>" --header "Content-Type: text/xml" --request PROPFIND url.com
```

By reading the curl man page I could not understand how the above commandline is using `--data` option.

Question:

1. What does above commandline do ?
2. Why doesn't man page describe this usage? If it does then what did I not understand after reading the man page?

Answer (score 6):

The `--data` flag is for defining `POST` data.

The command sends a `POST` with contents `<xml>` and MIME type `text/xml`. However, with the flag `--request`, you are setting the HTTP method from `POST` to `PROPFIND` and sending the request to `url.com`.

I also did manage to find the `--data` flag in the manual:

> `-d, --data <data>`
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.
>
> -d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. To post data purely binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the
>   value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.
>
> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command
>   line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a
>   separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would
>   generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.
>
> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file
>   name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data
>   from stdin. The contents of the file must already be URL-encoded.
>   Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named
>   'foobar' would thus be done with --data @filename. When --data is told
>   to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be
>   stripped out.